# Win10 How to Remove Background Picture For One Monitor Only

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, desktop-customization, background

I have 2 monitors and inadvertently set the same picture as the background for each monitor.  I wanted one solid color and the picture on the other but now I can only change them to both solid or a picture (same or different) on each.  When I choose Solid Color both monitors go solid and when I choose Picture both get a picture. There doesn't appear to be a way to change only one of the monitors to a solid color.

To find where individual monitor backgrounds are stored I created a new test user and set each monitor's background to different pictures/file names.  I then searched the registry for the file names of both images.  I found one monitor picture but not the other.

I'd also like to delete one of the pictures I set from the Background settings choice of pictures.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you set the monitor to Duplicate instead of Extend? Press Win+P and check you're using Extend.

Comment: They are set to Extended.

Comment: You could make a small picture of the colour you want and set it as the background for your 2nd monitor. If you right click a picture in the background settings window it lets you set it on just one specific monitor.

Comment: @Romen good idea for a workaround.   I'd like to understand why I can't revert back and then set the picture on one monitor.  Perhaps there's a registry setting I can reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears what I am asking can't be done according to Microsoft.  They suggested the same workaround @Romen suggested about using a color for a picture.

However, if you create a user, set the background to a solid color and then only change one monitor to picture it works fine until you change off of the Picture background setting to Solid or Slideshow.  Once you do that and try to go back to Picture, both monitors show up in picture mode.  So initially it works but you can't change the paradigm.

From Microsoft:

```
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-win_theme/win10-how-to-remove-background-picture-for-one/2203379c-7b51-48e2-a942-fac341de1771?messageId=6c5d704a-a1c3-4175-af86-a8336915060f&tm=1603734584257
        
There is no native function in the Windows display or Personalization settings to have a picture and a solid color on different monitor. However, you can work around this by creating an image of the desired solid color, then using it as a background image and applying it to one of the monitors.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found where the picture history is set in the registry but not how to revert back to a picture on  single monitor yet.  Deleting BackgroundHistoryPath entry data removed the pictures from the choices on the Background setting.  You have to log off to make the settings take.

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Wallpapers

Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2576265625-2187756292-1485823895-1001\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Wallpapers
```

Current wallpaper settings are found here (the user names may be different)

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop

Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-19\Control Panel\Desktop

Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20\Control Panel\Desktop
```